# Using map with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a server with NodeJS and keeping an account. Since the accounts are kept in the map, the map disappears when the server restarts. I prefer to use 'fs' to solve this. When the server starts, take it from a saved folder and set it to map and save the map to a folder every 30 seconds. How can I do this or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Typically user accounts are stored in databases, but you can use the filesystem to save your data if a database is out of the question.

Comment: You should not be storing accounts in the filesystem, but if you asked yourself if a breach is okay and you answered yes; it's fine in practice. Use a a timeout or interval to loop the process how you want.

Comment: To elaborate on breach, if your "accounts" contained sensitive information and this leaked by an exploit or hack. Would you and your users (if users) using the account be jeopardized?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JS objects instead of `map` you can use `JSON.stringify` method to convert the object to a string and then store it to file system. Imagine something like this:

```
const database = {"user1": {"some": "data"}, "user2": {"some": "data"}};
const serializedDatabase = JSON.stringify(database);
fs.writeFileSync("./data/database.json", serializedDatabase);
```

You can run this code inside `setInterval` loop to make it run every 30 seconds:

```
setInterval(() => {
    const serializedDatabase = JSON.stringify(database);
    fs.writeFileSync("./data/database.json", serializedDatabase);
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Then, if you want to read the data once you start you application, just `require` the file:

```
const database = require("./data/database.json");
```

You will get your data in memory. Some points:

- If you do it this way you can lose data. If your server crashes 20 seconds after last save you are going to lose every data stored to memory in the last 20 seconds.
- Method `writeFile` should be probably used instead of `writeFileSync` to make it non-blocking.
- In general, storing data to file system by hand is hard and tricky. Using a real database us usually a better call.
- If you don't have any "big" database such as MySQL or MongoDB, you can use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). It stores all the data to a single file. It's quite easy to use and if you want to migrate it somewhere else you just copy one file.